# How to fix "Specify which project or solution file to use" error where there's only one project in the folder?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dotnet-cli

Doing a `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` command, I got this error I hadn't gotten before in this project:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file.

There is only one project in the folder (and a `.sln` file) and in the past I haven't gotten this error.<sup>1</sup> [A search of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=MSBUILD+%3A+error+MSB1011%3A+%22Specify+which+project+or+solution+file+to+use+because+this+folder+contains+more+than+one+project+or+solution+file.%22) turned up multiple questions, but their answers (where they exist) were either multiple projects in the folder or environment issues.

How do I get the command working again?

---

<sup>1</sup> I see multiple answers saying it won't work if you have both a `.csproj` and a `.sln` in the same folder. It does (or at least, did) work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why they use that error message for it, but the problem was that I had the project running in Visual Studio. *(Doh!)* Apparently, when the project is running, this is the error it gives you (as opposed to, say, something telling you the project is running and that it can't do its job when the project is running). Stopping the run made the command work again.

Comment: *(Dumb mistake? Yes. But a Q&A here on SO saying "you may be making this dumb mistake" would have saved me something like half an hour of time. Hence, this Q&A...)*

Comment: *("Half an hour?!" you may wonder. Yeah, I hate to admit it, but yeah. I was working with multiple interacting projects running in debug at the same time and stopped the wrong one. Add to that the fact I hadn't had to do this in at least a year and had upgraded VS.Net recently. So my mind went down the rabbit hole of "did the tool change?" and, well, ... :-| )*